# pull records that are inactive

Tags: sql-server-2008, query, subquery

I need help with this query. I have records in customer table

```
 Main table - M

+---------+---------+----------+
| company | Account |  Active  |
+---------+---------+----------+
| A       | A123    | Active   |
| A       | A123    | InActive |
| B       | B123    | Inactive |
+---------+---------+----------+


Reference table - R

+---------+---------+
| company | Account |
+---------+---------+
| A       | A123    |
| B       | B123    |
| C       | C123    |
+---------+---------+
```

Pull all records from M which exists in R but are inactive. The problem here is a company may have both an inactive and an active account in M, I want to pull only those that only have inactive account and no active account. So from the two table, I should get

```
+---------+---------+----------+
| company | Account |  Active  |
+---------+---------+----------+
| B       | B123    | Inactive |
+---------+---------+----------+
```

Because A while it does exist in R, it also has an Active Account status so I must exclude it.

Comment: Have you tried a `JOIN`? Or using the `EXISTS`?

Comment: that's what I have been trying for the past hour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> a company may have both an inactive and an active account in M

SO I assume it can be only *one* active and *one* inactive row. Here is a solution with JOINs only. If there can be multiple (active) rows, you should use `EXISTS` instead, as @ypercube already mentioned in his comment.

```
SELECT R.*, M1.active
FROM   R
JOIN   M AS M1 ON M1.company = R.company
              AND M1.account = R.account
              AND M1.active  = 'inactive'
LEFT   JOIN M AS M2 ON M2.company = R.company
                   AND M2.account = R.account -- or no active account at all?
                   AND M2.active  = 'active'
WHERE  M2.company IS NULL;
```

As @ypercube commented: it did not become entirely clear whether you don't want *any* active account to invalidate the company or just a *matching* active account.

I went with `matching` account in my query. Remove `AND M2.account = R.account` from the JOIN condition if you want `any`.

Comment: The `AND M2.account = R.account` may need to be removed. OP's sample suggests it should be there. The explanation suggests the opposite.

Comment: +1 It worked. There is is s light mistake. The first active ='active' should be 'inactive' and the second active to return correct result. The query as it is gives me all active only records.

Comment: @Jackofall: Right, you want inactive ones, amended my answer. Cool that it works. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select R.company, R.account, 'InActive' as Active
from M join R on R.company = M.company
group by R.company, R.account
having count(*) =1 and min(Active) = 'InActive'
```

Comment: Bear in mind that I can have 2 or 3 inactive accounts with no active. Will it catch those?